# Topic consumption rate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to know the rate at which a topic is being consumed. There are `Messages in /sec` in the Kafka-manager metric, but there is no `Messages out /sec` I want. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka brokers do not have `Messages out /sec` metrics because when batches are sent to consumers they are not decompressed hence brokers do not know the exact raw message count.

Kafka brokers have `bytes out / sec` metrics per topic. That usually gives a good idea of consuemr activity. If you know the average message size, you can deduce a rough estimate of the messages out / sec value. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring

On the other hand, Kafka Consumers do expose received messages rates: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_fetch_monitoring

Comment: Can I get and calculate the difference of the current topic offset by a few seconds interval as `Messages out /sec`？

Comment: @Cheng I would recommend monitoring consumer lag to know messages in rate per consumer group. You can use a tool like Burrow or Remora to do this https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora